# What's the name of the father that Jesus came in?

Tags: john, matthew, new-testament, names-of-god

*Matthew 21 (KJV)
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
⁹ And the multitudes that went before, and that followed, cried, saying, Hosanna to the Son of David: **Blessed is he that cometh in the name of the Lord**; Hosanna in the highest.*

*John 5 (KJV)
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
⁴³ **I am come in my Father's name**, and ye receive me not: if another shall come in his own name, him ye will receive.
⁴⁴ How can ye believe, which receive honour one of another, and seek not the honour that cometh from God only?*

*John 17 (KJV)
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
⁶ **I have manifested thy name unto the men** which thou gavest me out of the world: thine they were, and thou gavest them me; and they have kept thy word.*

Jesus came in His father's name, what is that name? We know that God manifested Himself as I AM WHO I AM in the OT. Jesus doesn't talk much about that name, is there another name that we are missing?

Comment: 'Father' is the name that Jesus uses of his God. See his prayer in John 17 where he addresses God by name, 'Father'. And when he asks forgiveness for those who crucified him, 'Father, forgive them.'

Comment: Is father the name?

Comment: Yes. That is how Jesus addresses him. The name of that Divine Person is revealed to be, 'Father'. That is how his sons address him. But the world cannot address him so. 'Ye must be born again' to do so.

Comment: In the name of the father and of the son and of the Holy Spirit. The name of the son is Jesus, why say Father is the name? Is the name above all names given unto us?

Comment: Isn't this the name of the Lord?    Philippians 2 (KJV)

⁹ Wherefore God also hath highly exalted him, and given him a name which is above every name:
¹⁰ That at the name of Jesus every knee should bow, of things in heaven, and things in earth, and things under the earth;
¹¹ And that every tongue should confess that Jesus Christ is Lord, to the glory of God the Father.
https://zbible.page.link/nkjv

Comment: God, the Father (who sent his Son, Jesus Christ) is addressed as 'Father' That is his name.

Comment: Well, it doesn't sound like a name to me, biblically and logically. May be if you give some scriptures to support your opinion. John 5 (KJV)

⁴³ I am come in my Father's name, and ye receive me not: if another shall come in his own name, him ye will receive. ** Jesus came in His father's name, how comes FATHER be the name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122394/discussion-between-charles-mbogo-and-nigel-j).

Comment: The name of the Father is "the Holy Spirit"

Comment: Yes, let's continue in chat. What's your view considering Philippians 2:10?

Comment: Why say so, Constantthin? What scripture says the name of the father is Holy Spirit?

Answer (score 2):

The word "name" here has multiple meanings.

First, It is often used to designate the person himself.
Jesus use this word to refer to himself in

> John 15:21
> They will treat you this way because of my **name**, for they do not know the one who sent me.
>
> Matthew 10:22
> and you will be hated by all for my **name’s** sake. But the one who endures to the end will be saved.

Second, the word "name" includes the attributes or character of God especially his authority and power.

> Exdous 20:20 “See, I am sending an angel ahead of you to guard you along the way and to bring you to the place I have prepared. 21Pay attention to him and listen to what he says. Do not rebel against him; he will not forgive your rebellion, since my **Name** is in him.
>
> Proverbs 18:10
> The **name** of the LORD is a fortified tower; the righteous run to it and are safe.

Third, it is the incommunicable name.

> Philippians 2:9
> Therefore God exalted him to the highest place and gave him the **name** that is above every name,

What's the name of the father that Jesus came in?

I don't think it is productive to look for some kind of secret properly-spelled name here. The word "name" carries the above 3 meanings.

Comment: Very well-said, I was about to make a similar observation - coming in X's name frequently indicates coming in representation of X or with authority from X.

Comment: Thanks. This is still true and practiced in China today.

Answer (score 2):

‘Name’ had more than one meaning in biblical times; a point lost on most people today. We are inclined to think of what’s written on our birth certificates as our name/s, so your name may be Charles Mbogo, and you are asking if God the Father has a similar personal name designation. While it is true that ‘God’ is a general title and not a personal name, there are ways of differentiating God the Father from all the other gods one hears of in this world. “Father” is one such designation that differentiates him, as is “Almighty”.

It also needs to be borne in mind that coming in the ‘name’ of someone means coming in that one’s authority, as representative, as speaking what that one would speak if personally present, and doing what that one would do if personally present. Ambassadors have that authority, when representing their nation’s government, or king or queen, while living in a different country. They come, speak, and act “in the name of” their appointed government, king or queen. That is their authority.

Critical to grasping what Jesus meant by coming in the name of the Father, and of how the Jews he spoke to understood this, is to see the context of passages such as John chapter 5 of which you only quote two verses. Consider first what led to the debate about Jesus and in whose name he came, and it soon becomes apparent what he meant by coming in the name of the Father, and why God’s name, ‘Father,’ is so significant.

The Jews had taken offense at Jesus healing a lame man on the Sabbath, to the extent that they wanted to kill Jesus (5:16 The Companion Bible). Jesus told them, “My Father worketh hitherto, and I work.” “Therefore the Jews sought the more to kill him, because he not only had broken the sabbath, but said also that God was his Father, making himself equal with God.” (5:17-18) That is a crucial point so often overlooked by readers of the text. It shows the unique significance of calling God “Father”.  For a Jewish man like Jesus to do that meant he was making himself equal with God.

This outraged his critics. So, Jesus explained that he, the Son of God, could do nothing of himself, but only what he saw the Father do – that the Son does what the Father does. He even went so far as to say that the Father had given him authority to raise, and judge, the dead “so that all men should honour the Son, even as they honour the Father. He that honoureth not the Son honoureth not the Father which has sent him.” (5:19-23)

Now, his critics were used to rabbis coming in the name of others of great authority, and they accepted them on the basis of knowing the ones whose names they claimed as their authority. There was a tradition of rabbis listing various acclaimed (and usually long-dead) rabbis whose work they believed and promoted, continuing the ‘line’ of teaching of the original rabbi whose school they represented. This was what Jesus’ critics were expecting him to list – human religious teachers they already knew of. If he came in their ‘name’ [authority] they would accept him. But Jesus ignored all the middle-men. He went right to the top – to God the Father, personally! He came in the name of the Father! That must have sent them into fits of apoplexy.

Now we can grasp the significance of verses 43 and 44, which you quoted. It also lends new significance to his words in verses 31-44, that Christ does not receive honour from men, though they did. As Matthew Henry’s comment states, he came not to seek his own glory.

> “…they obstinately opposed him who was the true Messias (v. 43)… Those
> are false prophets who come in their own name, who run without being
> sent… They therefore slighted and undervalued Christ because they
> admired and overvalued themselves…  He did not covet nor court the
> applause of men, did not in the least affect that worldly pomp and
> splendour in which the carnal Jews expected their Messiah to appear.”
> (p 1554)

In Judaism, certain rabbis came to be so acclaimed that anyone promoting his school of teaching would be accepted. The schools of Shammai and Hillel were current in Jesus’ day. Had he cited them as his authority, he could have been accepted. (Yet, even though his account in Luke 16:13-31 agreed with those schools on that point, he was hated for saying it because it was an expose of the love of money the Pharisees had.) Then, long after Christ, for example, rabbi Maimonides (1135-1204) is still, to this day, upheld as an authority for establishing the Thirteen Principles of the Faith. Again, a later and different religious tradition relies heavily on tracing a line of teachers to authenticate their ‘Hadith’ as almost equivalent in authority to their Qur’an. These ‘traditions’ have to have a traceable line going back to Mohammed, then they will be accepted, and they are considered to be very important for all Muslims to believe. [Sources: The Encyclopedia of World Faiths edited by Peter Bishop & Michael Darton, pp37-38 & Islam, the way of submission, by Solomon Nigosian, Crucible, pp 122-129]

Finally, Jesus culminated his exquisite case by calling himself the I AM (John 8:54-59). Whereas you said, “We know that God manifested Himself as I AM WHO I AM in the OT. Jesus doesn't talk much about that name,” the astounding fact is that he only needed to call himself by that divine name once, and he nearly got stoned to death for it. That is the power and the authority of taking the very name of God upon himself. And his critics knew it, for they knew there was only one God and Father, and that Jesus came in the unique name of God the Father, being his Son.

Answer (score 1):

**What does Matthew 21:1-9 reference? - The prophecy of [the] Word of YHVH ( מַשָּׂ֚א דְבַר־יְהֹוָה֙ ) in Zechariah 9.**

- Matthew 21:5 testifies that the prophecy of Zechariah 9:9 is being fulfilled.
- Zechariah 9:9 describes the entry of the King of Jerusalem (Yerushalaim, יְרוּשָׁלִַ֔ם). “Rejoice greatly, Fair Zion; Raise a shout, Fair Jerusalem! Lo, your king is coming to you. He is victorious, triumphant, Yet humble, riding on an ass, On a donkey foaled by a she-donkey” ( גִּילִ֨י מְאֹ֜ד בַּת־צִיּ֗וֹן הָרִ֙יעִי֙ בַּ֣ת יְרוּשָׁלִַ֔ם הִנֵּ֤ה מַלְכֵּךְ֙ יָ֣בוֹא לָ֔ךְ צַדִּ֥יק וְנוֹשָׁ֖ע ה֑וּא עָנִי֙ וְרֹכֵ֣ב עַל־חֲמ֔וֹר וְעַל־עַ֖יִר בֶּן־אֲתֹנֽוֹת )

**Zechariah 9:14** clarifies in whose Name the King comes in:
“And YHVH shall appear over them, and his arrows shall go forth like lightning. And [the] Lord YHVH shall sound the shofar, and He shall go with the whirlwinds of the south.” ( וַֽיהֹוָה֙ עֲלֵיהֶ֣ם יֵֽרָאֶ֔ה וְיָצָ֥א כַבָּרָ֖ק חִצּ֑וֹ וַֽאדֹנָ֚י יֱהֹוִה֙ בַּשּׁוֹפָ֣ר יִתְקָ֔ע וְהָלַ֖ךְ בְּסַֽעֲר֥וֹת תֵּימָֽן )

**Zechariah 9:16** clarifies again that the prophecy in Zechariah 9 describes how YHVH יְהֹוָ֧ה will use the King [verse 9] to save His people. “And YHVH their God shall save them on that day like the flocks of His people, for crown stones are exalted on His land.” ( וְֽהוֹשִׁיעָ֞ם יְהֹוָ֧ה אֱלֹהֵיהֶ֛ם בַּיּ֥וֹם הַה֖וּא כְּצֹ֣אן עַמּ֑וֹ כִּי אַבְנֵי־נֵ֔זֶר מִתְנֽוֹסְס֖וֹת עַל־אַדְמָתֽוֹ )

**To clarify the name of the King which YHVH is describing to Zechariah 9, YHVH tells us in Exodus 23:21.**

- Exodus 23:21 - “Beware of him and obey him; do not rebel against him, for he will not forgive your transgression, for **My NAME** is within him." (הִשָּׁ֧מֶר מִפָּנָ֛יו וּשְׁמַ֥ע בְּקֹל֖וֹ אַל־תַּמֵּ֣ר בּ֑וֹ כִּ֣י לֹ֤א יִשָּׂא֙ לְפִשְׁעֲכֶ֔ם כִּ֥י שְׁמִ֖י בְּקִרְבּֽוֹ )

In **Exodus 3:15**, God clarifies His NAME to Moses : "And God said further to Moses, "So shall you say to the children of Israel, 'YHVH - God of your forefathers, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob, has sent me to you.' This is **My NAME** forever, and this is how I should be mentioned in every generation." (וַיֹּ֩אמֶר֩ ע֨וֹד אֱלֹהִ֜ים אֶל־משֶׁ֗ה כֹּ֣ה תֹאמַר֘ אֶל־בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵל֒ יְהֹוָ֞ה אֱלֹהֵ֣י אֲבֹֽתֵיכֶ֗ם אֱלֹהֵ֨י אַבְרָהָ֜ם אֱלֹהֵ֥י יִצְחָ֛ק וֵֽאלֹהֵ֥י יַֽעֲקֹ֖ב שְׁלָחַ֣נִי אֲלֵיכֶ֑ם זֶה־שְּׁמִ֣י לְעֹלָ֔ם וְזֶ֥ה זִכְרִ֖י לְדֹ֥ר דֹּֽר)

**We know "Yeshua" was an abbreviated name for "Yehoshua" (during the 2nd Temple period) based on [Ezra 3:2]. The Hebrew meaning of Messiah's name יֵשׁ֨וּעַ "Yeshua" (Yehoshua) יְהוֹשֻׁ֤עַ is "YHVH-[is]-salvation".**

Comment: Can we therefore say that Jesus came with the name YHWH? When it says "my name is within him" isn't this referring to the Holy Spirit? Then revelations 19:12-13 gives us a secret name as well, THE WORD OF GOD. Doesn't this name match John 1? Thanks for your elaboration

Comment: Based on Ezra 3:2, we know "Yeshua" was an abbreviated name for "Yehoshua" (during the 2nd Temple period). The abbreviated name Yeshua answers your question regarding God's NAME being in him. The transliterated name "Jesus" loses the Hebrew meaning of the name.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the name of the father that Jesus came in?

Perhaps this question is equivalent to a similar question:

> What's the name of The Law that the sheriff, bailiff, police, etc. are referring to when they say "Open the door in the name of the law!"?

In this context, it doesn't mean a literal name; it means that the legal system has given this person authority to perform certain actions. The Law requires that people must open their door when requested in order for those actions to be carried out.

Answer (score -1):

All we know about God's name is the Hebrew letters transliterated YHWH.  They read YHWH as Adonai (Lord) when reading scripture or praying.  For other cases they say Adoshai for Adonai, Eloshim for Elohim, and write G-d for God.  For YHWH they will say Hashem, the Name.